# Ansible Shell Cannot Pull Docker Image

Tags: shell, docker, ansible, dockerhub, dockerpy

I've run into issues pulling Docker images from a private DockerHub repo using the Docker module of Ansible, so to sanity-check that code decided to try pulling the image in question first using the shell. This also fails. What's going on here? If I SSH onto the box, I am able to run *exactly the same command* in the shell and it works, pulling the right image.

Isolated example play:

```
---
- hosts: <host-ip>
  gather_facts: True
  remote_user: ubuntu
  sudo: yes

  tasks:
  - include_vars: vars/client_vars.yml
  - name: Pull stardog docker image [private]
    shell: sudo docker pull {{stardog_docker_repo}}

  - name: Tag stardog docker image [private]
    shell: sudo docker tag {{stardog_docker_repo}} stardog_tag
```

The error that's being output is:

```
failed: [<host-ip>] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sudo docker pull <org>/<image>:latest", "delta": "0:00:01.395931", "end": "2015-08-05 17:35:22.480811", "rc": 1, "start": "2015-08-05 17:35:21.084880", "warnings": []}
stderr: Error: image <org>/<image>:latest not found
stdout: Pulling repository <org>/<image>

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

NB: I've sanitised my `<org>` and `<image>` but rest assured their image identifier in the playbook and error logging perfectly match the image that I can successfully run in the shell over ssh by doing:

```
$ sudo docker pull <org>/<image>:latest
```

I'm aware of various GitHub issues ([like this one](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/940) I had when using the Docker module), patches et cetera related to the `docker-py` library, but the thing here is I'm just using the Ansible `shell` module. What have I missed?

Answer (score 4):

A colleague of mine pointed out something - if you log the `env`, you find that the `sudo: yes` makes `root` run the docker commands by default and thus the `ubuntu` user's Docker credentials are not picked up. This playbook works (assuming you have a valid `dockercfg.json` in the `docker` folder, relative to this playbook.

```
---
- hosts: <host-ip>
  gather_facts: True
  remote_user: ubuntu
  sudo: yes

  tasks:
  - include_vars: vars/client_vars.yml
  # run the docker tasks

  - name: Add docker credentials for ubuntu user
    copy: src=docker/dockercfg.json dest=/root/.dockercfg

  - name: Get env
    shell: sudo env
    register: sudo_env

  - name: Debug
    debug: msg="{{sudo_env}}"

  - name: Pull stardog docker image [private]
    shell: docker pull {{stardog_docker_repo}}

  - name: Tag stardog docker image [private]
    shell: docker tag {{stardog_docker_repo}} stardog_tag
```

This gives `root` the right DockerHub creds. Alternatively, you can add `sudo: false` to each of the plays and use sudo inline on each `shell` call to run as the `ubuntu` user.

Comment: The file was `~/.docker/config.json` for me, but the idea was exactly what I needed to solve the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use Ansible's docker_container 
 module to pull image now.

In this way, you don't need to run sudo in shell.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_container_module.html